# Parsing C# Script into Java

Tags: c#, java, database, parsing, file-io

I'm looking for a way to easily read in a C# file and place it into a Java Object for database storage (storing the class name, functions, variables, etc).

I'm making a Hierarchical State Machine AI Building Tool for a game I'm creating and need to be able to import an existing C# file and store it in a database for retrieval in the future.

Does anyone know of any preexisting libraries for parsing C# files? Something similar to [JavaParser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/)?

Thanks everyone!

**EDIT**: This needs to be part of my Java Project. I'll be loading in the C# files through my Java Application and saving it into my db4o database.

Comment: storing the entire file as text is not an option?

Comment: Correct. I'm storing the functions as classes, so I can easily add and edit them while doing linking between classes (for the HSM).

Comment: +1 for the link to javaparser... didnt know about that

Answer (score 1):

You could use Roslyn, but it would be a bit of work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn

Roslyn is only in Preview, by the way. Microsoft hasn't said when the actual release will be out.

This is a C# library. You will need to do the actual parsing with a C# program using Roslyn.

Comment: Can this be part of a Java project? I need to be able to use this in my Java project.

Comment: It's a C# library, so you'd need a C# program to do the actual parsing.

Comment: You're really not going to get much better than Roslyn (it's what the new C# compiler is going to be written in), no matter what language you choose. I'd suggest writing a C# portion of your project that does the actual parsing. Maybe you could invoke the C# portion through Java, though I'm not sure exactly how (if) that can be done.

Answer (score -1):

[This page](http://www.infoq.com/news/grasshopper_2_ctp) talks about an IL to Java byte code compiler called grasshopper, but it doesn't seem to be there anymore. Maybe you could have done that and use reflection after loading the compilates, not sure where that leaves the code itself, if you need that as well.